# Gulp-rev different path in manifest.json

Tags: path, gulp, manifest, gulp-rev, manifest.json

I am now trying to generate manifest.json file with gulp-rev. What I need is something like this:

```
     {
      "img/image.jpg": "folder/img/image-34c9d558b2.jpg";
}
```

How do I put that "folder" in path there? I was trying to use gulp-rev-collector but it was not very useful. Could someone give me an example please?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your gulpfile?

Comment: I have already solve it, answers below. Thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me was using `gulp-rename` and then doing something like:

```
.pipe($.rename({
  dirname: 'styles',
}))
.pipe($.rev.manifest('manifest.json', {
  cwd: 'build',
  merge: true,
}))
```

However, what *ultimately* worked for me was using `gulp-rev` in combination with `gulp-rev-collector`, the latter which replaces the links as per the mappings found in the manifest files.

So something like:

```
.pipe($.rename({
  dirname: 'styles',
}))
.pipe($.rev())
.pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/styles'))
.pipe($.rev.manifest())
.pipe(gulp.dest('build/styles'));
```

And also adding a new `rev` task for `gulp-rev-collector`

```
// Revision static asset files
gulp.task('rev', () =>
  gulp.src(['build/**/rev-manifest.json', 'build/*.html'])
    .pipe($.revCollector())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build')),
);
```

Comment: Yeah, I had already use not so different solution -> I also change generated manifest.json plugin, but with gulp-replace. Thanks for your too!